# Active Admin filters not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm struggling with filters on the index view of my ActiveAdmin resource.

This is the abbrieviated source:

```
ActiveAdmin.register PendingCollege do
  config.clear_action_items!

  controller do
    include Sendable
  end

  filter :name

  menu :parent => "College"

  actions :all, :except => [:destroy, :edit]

  scope :all do
    PendingCollege
  end

  scope :pending, default: true do
    PendingCollege.pending
  end

  scope :rejected do
    PendingCollege.rejected
  end

  scope :accepted do
    PendingCollege.accepted
  end

  index do
    column :id
    column "Name", :name
    column "IPEDS Number", :ipeds_number
    column "Local id", :local_id
  end
end
```

The behavior I am seeing is that the filter shows up on the right as expected. When I select 'contains' and put a string in the box and hit the filter button, it reloads the page with the default scope but the results have not been filtered at all.

I verified that `"q"=>{"name_contains"=>"Adrian"}` is in the parameters to the controller, but the sql being run doesn't leverage that.

I basically added a single filter (rather than the default filters for every attribute) because there are TONS of searchable attributes that I don't need to expose in this interface.

I've looked at lots of code examples and haven't found anything where extra code had to be added to support the filters.

Comment: To clarify, `Sendable` is a module that has methods to send data to a remote RESTful api via http.

Answer (score 0):

You should define scopes like this:

```
scope :pending, default: true do |scope|
  # given scope has all applied filters at this moment
  scope.pending
end
```

In your case, since you have scopes with the same name in your model, you can simply do like this:

```
scope :all
scope :pending, default: true
scope :rejected
scope :accepted
```